# Sentry doesn't capture exceptions from Spark job

Tags: java, apache-spark, kotlin, sentry

My problem is that the code below throws an exception and I capture that with Sentry, but when I go to Sentry UI, the exception does not appear at all. I want to find a way where I could use Sentry across the spark driver and executors as well. Any ideas?

Also, I'm not sure what additional information is required, so feel free to let me know and I'll provide it.

Versions:

- `Spark: 2.12-3.0.0`
- `Sentry: 3.1.1`

```kotlin
import io.sentry.Sentry
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("myApp")
        .config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
        .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
        .getOrCreate()
        .use { sparkSession ->
            JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext()).let { sc ->
                Sentry.init { options ->
                    options.dsn = "********"
                }

                try {
                    throw Exception("exception before executors start working")
                } catch(e: Exception) {
                    Sentry.captureException(e)
                }

                // starting some executors and see if Sentry receives exceptions from them:
                sc.parallelize((0..100).toList(), 10).map { i ->                
                    try {
                        throw Exception("exception $i from worker")
                    } catch (e: Exception) {                        
                        Sentry.captureException(e)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I also tried to execute the inner `HubAdapter` from Sentry and use that as a `Broadcast` variable, but no luck.

**UPDATE #1**

Added debug option to Sentry init and tried starting and closing a session:

```
import io.sentry.Sentry
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("myApp")
        .config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
        .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
        .getOrCreate()
        .use { sparkSession ->
            JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext()).let { sc ->
                Sentry.init { options ->
                    options.dsn = "********"
                    options.isDebug = true
                }

                Sentry.startSession()

                try {
                    throw Exception("exception before executors start working")
                } catch(e: Exception) {
                    Sentry.captureException(e)
                }

                // starting some executors and see if Sentry receives exceptions from them:
                sc.parallelize((0..100).toList(), 10).map { i ->                
                    try {
                        throw Exception("exception $i from worker")
                    } catch (e: Exception) {                        
                        Sentry.captureException(e)
                    }
                }

                Sentry.endSession()
                Sentry.close()
            }
        }
}
```

Here's what I see in the logs:

```
INFO: Initializing SDK with DSN: '**********'
INFO: No outbox dir path is defined in options.
INFO: GlobalHubMode: 'false'
20/11/03 18:42:01 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.36.62.15:42123 with 4.6 GiB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, 10.36.62.15, 42123, None)
DEBUG: UncaughtExceptionHandlerIntegration enabled: true
DEBUG: UncaughtExceptionHandlerIntegration installed.
WARNING: Sessions can't be captured without setting a release.
DEBUG: Capturing event: 9b17170bdaf841cbb764969f653f99b5
ERROR: Request failed, API returned 400
ERROR: {"detail":"invalid event envelope","causes":["invalid item header","EOF while parsing an object at line 1 column 49"]}
WARNING: Sessions can't be captured without setting a release.
INFO: Closing SentryClient.
DEBUG: Shutting down
```

**UPDATE #2**:

Created [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/1026) for better visibility

Comment: Does the process exit right after you call Sentry.captureException? The events are submitted on the background so you need to call Sentry.close() before exiting to make sure events are flushed out before you exit

Comment: even if I put `Sentry.close()` to the end, nothing is shown in Sentry.

Comment: Add please `options.debug=true` to see the log messages. Perhaps there's something valuable there.

Comment: I've added an update with log entries I see after setting `options.debug = true`